# Problems with Haskell variable scope error and creating a proper type declaration

Tags: haskell

In most of my functions, I seem to get the common error of "Variable not in scope"
For example this function

```
zipmap :: [Int]->[Int]->[Int]
zipmap x y = map (\(a,b) -> a + b) (x zip y)
```

would give me "Variable not in scope: zipmap :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> t"

Why is this happening, and for future reference what can I do to avoid these errors?

Comment: `x zip y`? `zip` is just an ordinary function.

Comment: n.b. that `(\(a,b) -> a + b)` is just `(uncurry (+))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that there are already errors when you *define* the function. Since you fail to define the `zipmap` function, the interactive shell assumes nothing happened, and thus it does not know about a function `zipmap` later in the process. For example:

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 8.0.2: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> zipmap :: [Int]->[Int]->[Int]; zipmap x y = map (\(a,b) -> a + b) (x zip y)

<interactive>:1:68: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘([a0] -> [b0] -> [(a0, b0)])
                                    -> [Int] -> [(Int, Int)]’
                  with actual type ‘[Int]’
    • The function ‘x’ is applied to two arguments,
      but its type ‘[Int]’ has none
      In the second argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(x zip y)’
      In the expression: map (\ (a, b) -> a + b) (x zip y)
Prelude> zipmap [1,2,3] [1,4,2,5]

<interactive>:2:1: error:
    Variable not in scope: zipmap :: [Integer] -> [Integer] -> t
```

Note the part in boldface: the interpreter says it does not understand what you say, so it can not proceed with that. Then later if we use `zipmap`, it raises the same error like the one you describe.

Your `zipmap` function is wrong since you write:

```
x zip y
```

`zip :: [a] -> [b] -> [(a,b)]` is a function, not an operator, so you should use it as:

```
zip x y
```

Or in full:

```
zipmap :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
zipmap x y = map (\(a,b) -> a + b) (zip x y)
```

We can further improve this: there is a `zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]` function:

```
zipmap :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
zipmap x y = zipWith (+) x y
```

or even shorter:

```
zipmap :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
zipmap = zipWith (+)
```

and finally we can generalize our function:

```
zipmap :: Num a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
zipmap = zipWith (+)
```

Comment: I changed it to (zip x y) and it still gave me the error. I am using repl.it as my compiler since my school's computers don't have Haskell installed. Could that be the source of the error?

Comment: @STRAN: probably not. I can not reproduce the error with the correct `zipmap` on repl.it. Can you share a link to your repl?